# How to check that current space is Dashboard?

Tags: cocoa, space, dashboard, nsworkspace

Sample code is

```
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(activeSpaceDidChange:) name:NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Then

```
- (void) activeSpaceDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
         // code to check if current workspace is dashboard?
}
```

I want to check whether the current space is dashboard or not? Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

The first think i have tried is get to the current space id according to this answer: [Detecting when a space changes in Spaces in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414111/detecting-when-a-space-changes-in-spaces-in-mac-os-x) . The problem here is that the key `kCGWindowWorkspace` is deprecated in OSX 10.8. So there is no direct way to get this information.

In my solution now i check for different windows or owners which are only one the dashboard space or on all other spaces:

- The user is on the dashboard if there is one window which `kCGWindowName` ends with `.wdgt/`
- The user is **not** on the dashboard if there is one window with `kCGWindowName == System Status Item Clone`, `kCGWindowOwnerName == SystemUIServer | Finder`

So why i'm not just using the `.wdgt/` check? -- Because if there is now widget on the dashboard this not working

So why i'm using more than one window check? -. Because i'm not jet sure which window is always on all spaces. At least `System Status Item Clone` and `Finder` are not always there.

Here my implementation is add this function as category to NSWorkspace

```
- (BOOL) userIsOnDashboardSpace {

NSArray*  windowsInSpace = (__bridge NSArray *) CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionAll | kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);

NSUInteger indexOfWidget = [windowsInSpace indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    if ([obj objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowName]) {
        NSString *name = (NSString *)[obj objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowName];
        if ([name isEqualToString:@"System Status Item Clone"]) {
            *stop = true;
            return false;
        }            
        if ([name hasSuffix:@".wdgt/"]) {
            *stop = true;
            return true;
        }
    }        
    if ([obj objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowOwnerName]) {
        NSString *name = (NSString *)[obj objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowOwnerName];
        if ([name isEqualToString:@"SystemUIServer"]) {
            *stop = true;
            return false;
        }            
        if ([name isEqualToString:@"Finder"]) {
            *stop = true;
            return false;
        }       
    }

    return false;
}];    
return indexOfWidget != NSNotFound;
```

}