# How can I detect the screen has been changed via four fingers (mac os)?

Tags: jquery, css, macos, popup, phaser-framework

everybody!

I'm creating a small game

I have a popup that is shown when the cursor is over an element

Here is the method of creating a sprite:

```
createSprite: function(x, y, elementName) {
    var obj = game.add.sprite(x, y, elementName);
    //smth
    obj.events.onInputOver.add(this.activeSlot, this);
    //smth

    return obj;
}
```

here is the Method that is called when the cursor is over a sprite:

```
activeSlot: function(overElement) {
    //smth
    this.showPopupItem(overElement);
}
```

And here is showPopupItem method:

```
showPopupItem: function(overedElement) {
 //here I'm creating sprites and images that are shown
}
```

The popup is destroyed when the cursor is not over an element

---

Everything works fine, BUT here is one problem:

When I am hovering a sprite and then change the screen via four fingers on MAC OS, then I move mouse and so on, and then again the screen of the game is opened the popup doesn't hide at all

---

I wonder, what can I do with that

Thank you in advance for your answer)
Good luck!

Comment: I know you're using jquery, but if you can relate to the equivalent Objective-C code, perhaps [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414111/detecting-when-a-space-changes-in-spaces-in-mac-os-x) to point you in the right direction

Comment: @TheDarkKnight that's the main thing: my game is browser one

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `onTouchCancel` event. [Documentation](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.2/Phaser.Touch.html#onTouchCancel).